# Convert Rectangular Electrical Box in Ceiling to Octagon?

Tags: electrical

I need to do the opposite of what is talked about in this post: [Can I convert ceiling mounted octagon box to electrical receptacle?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/can-i-convert-ceiling-mounted-octagon-box-to-electrical-receptacle)

Specifically, there is a rectangular electrical box in my ceiling that I want to hang a light from. There is currently no outlet, switch, or other equipment hooked up to it - it has a solid cover screwed over the top of it. I am fairly certain that it is simply acting as a junction box for two independent sets of lights that are in the ceiling.

Any advice for how to go about this? Do I just cut out the old box and insert an old-work octagon into it? Conversely, is there a simple way to hang a ceiling light from a rectangular box?

Comment: You'll want to do box fill calculations before proceeding.  A square box may have been used to allow for the number of wires in the box.  An octagonal box is likely smaller, and so does not allow as many wires.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You said "rectangular" and "receptacle" so you probably have one half this size, not a square box...

There is a simple way to hang a light from a square box. You may have to look around a bit, but there is a mud ring/reducer that goes from square to round (and the round has the screw positions/spacing so a light fixture attachment will fit.)

[image: Mud Ring] *Image is from Crescent electric supply web site.*

I have a couple of these myself. The adapter ring was in stock but not prominently displayed where I bought it, so it took a little hunting. 2-3/4" is the spacing for the inner screws - I think there's also a smaller one (2-23/32") for smaller fixture spacings.

Comment: This. So much this.